# How to get the value of Jquery UI slider? With 2 or more slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Currently, I am using Jquery UI slider to get a rating scale of user. There exist not only a slider but more than 2. How do I get the value of each according each name? I had to accumulate them the total value according the different name.
[Jquery UI slider Please click for snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/cdkskkLg/#&togetherjs=qk10PLnUJf)

```
Jquery UI slider
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to write up some code to build an associated array that maps the name of the slider to the value.

```
r = {}
$( ".slider" ).each(function () {
  r[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).slider("option", "value");
});
console.log(r);
```

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 1
}).on("slidestop", function () {
  r = {}
  $( ".slider" ).each(function () {
  r[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).slider("option", "value");
});
console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I want the value change when I drag the slider, just use onchange? Or there is some other method?

Comment: `$(".slider").change(function() {
 r = {}
 $( ".slider" ).each(function () {
   r[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).slider("option", "value");
 });
 console.log(r);
});
`

I write like this but it seem no working for me =(

Comment: @Beginner Updated the post

Comment: Thanks! It finally work ^^ However, the `slidestop` is one of the event function?

Comment: Yeah I think it's just for jQuery UI slider.

Comment: Thanks, you a genius =)